# What result should I return from DBIx::Class::ResultSet::* methods?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have next code:

```
#find contact with given email and/or phone
sub contact {
    my( $self, $email, $phone ) =  @_;

    my $user =  $self;
    $user =  $user->search({ email => $email })   if $email;
    $user =  $user->search({ phone => $phone })   if $phone;

    return $user->first; # I think this is wrong
}
```

It it OK that in my `ArtCoin::Schema::ResultSet::User` package to return `Result`?

Comment: Wat do you want to do with it? Do you want the first record, or do you want a prebuilt resultset that you can use to do more stuff?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered, it depends on what you need. You can define what the returned result is.

Answer (score 2):

When you build a custom ResultSet, you typically return the new ResultSet object. In [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#Custom-ResultSet-classes) the examples contain an implicit `return`.

> ```
> sub active {
>   my $self = shift;
>   $self->search({ $self->current_source_alias . '.active' => 1 });
> }
> ```

Because there is no `return`, it just returns the return value of the last statement. That's the `$self->search(...)` part.

So your code would be like this:

```
sub contact {
    my( $self, $email, $phone ) =  @_;

    my $user =  $self;
    $user =  $user->search({ email => $email })   if $email;
    $user =  $user->search({ phone => $phone })   if $phone;

    return $user;
}
```

Remember that the ResultSet is not actually a result. There has not been a query at that point. If you call `->first` on it in your method, it will talk to the database and run your query. After that, you cannot chain additional `search`es to the ResultSet, because you don't have a ResultSet any more.

---

The following section is a bit of code-review.

What you did there works quite well, but it's a bit complex. You are chaining up to two additional searches, which translate to more stuff that DBIC needs to do for you in the background. Think about how that method should behave.

Right now, it does this:

- if there are no arguments `$rs->contact()`, it will return the same ResultSet as before, without any new search criteria (`SELECT * FROM contacts`)
- if there was the email argument `$rs->contact($email)`, it will return a new ResultSet that has an additional search criteria for the email (`SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email='...'`)
- if there was the phone argument `$rs->contacts( undef, $phone )`, it will return a new ResultSet that has an additional search criteria for the phone (`SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE phone='...'`)
- if there were both email and phone arguments `$rs->contacts( $email, $phone )`, it will return a new ResultSet that has two additional search criteria (`SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email='...' AND phone='...'`)

That makes sense, but for the first case. If you don't want any narrowing down, you'd not call that method in the first place, would you?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you need.
I prefix all methods returning ResultSets with 'search_' and all that return a single object 'find_'.